# There are sets $A,B$, and $C$ such that $A∈B,B∈C$, and $C∈A$. How to avoid Axiom of regularity, since Halmos avoids it in his Naive Set Theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Give an example or disprove: There are sets $A, B$, and $C$ such that $A ∈ B,B ∈ C$, and $C ∈ A$.
How can I do this without using the Axiom of regularity, since Halmos avoids it in his Naive Set Theory?

Comment: You cannot prove or disprove this in ZF minus regularity (unless ZF is inconsistent). Adding regularity disproves the existence, adding Aczel's Anti-Foundation axiom yields a Quine atom $x$ and you can take $A=B=C= x$.

Comment: @Arturo: Actually, adding AFA we can find a lot of different examples of these sort of chains.